# Woocommerce customize the product name in the cart and order pages

Tags: wordpress, cart, woocommerce

Actually, I already got hook to customize the price in the cart page and all other page.

This is the hook to customize the product price

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price' );

function add_custom_price( $cart_object ) {
    $custom_price = 10; // This will be your custome price  
    foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {
        $value['data']->price = $custom_price;
    }
}
```

Actually, I am using woocommerce plugin. I want a hook to customize the product name displayed in the cart page and all other pages next to cart page.

I want to customize the Product name , i want to add the some static attributes to product name displayed in the cart page, order page ,order details page and all the pages next to cart page.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to share this as I managed to figure out something for my needs. **(I only ever have a single item in the order as I've customised WooCommerce for holiday bookings.)**

```
<?php
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_title', 'add_custom_name' );
function add_custom_name( $title ) {
    return 'test name';
}
?>
```

Hopefully someone can elaborate on this further or take what has been done with the custom price code an properly re-purpose it for product names.